# Landing Page responsiva com bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando criar a seguinte disposição na minha landing page:
[image: Layout criado no photoshop]

Porém, ao tentar criar isso em HTML, não consigo fazer com que as imagens façam essa lista. Estou tentando usar a classe "deck", sem sucesso.

```
 <section class="success" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>ASSISTA</h2>
                <hr class="star-light">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143313674" width="550" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/143313674"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-push-2">
            <div class="deck"> <img src="img/portfolio/submarine.png" width="100" height="100" style="display:block"> <div class="figure illustration ng-isolate-scope lazy-canceled" lazy-load="figures" style="display: block;"> <div class="lyft-classic"></div> </div> <div class="body grid-center"> <h3>SOCIAL</h3> <p>Com um viés social e espírito de equipe. </p> </div> </div>
            <div class="deck"> <img src="img/portfolio/submarine.png" width="100" height="100" style="display:block"> <div class="figure illustration ng-isolate-scope lazy-canceled" lazy-load="figures" style="display: block;"> <div class="lyft-classic"></div> </div> <div class="body grid-center"> <h3>SOCIAL</h3> <p>Com um viés social e espírito de equipe. </p> </div> </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Lembrando que gostaria de fazer com que isso seja responsivo, gostaria de saber se pelo menos estou fazendo o nesting das divs da maneira correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, acredito que esteja no caminho certo.
Eu criei um JSBin para estudar seu código e fiz uma regra CSS.
Veja se era isto que precisava
https://jsbin.com/biqawo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Rodrigo, quando abro numa janela comum, a disposição fica legal. O vídeo ainda fica um pouco menor do que eu gostaria, pois pretendo inserir 3 títulos do lado direito. Quando testo no Teste de compatibilidade com dispositivos móveis do Google, ele não fica responsivo. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: 1 - Vídeo menor: Você deve alterar a largura, mudando a classe "col-sm-4" para "col-sm-5" ou maiores, de acordo com sua necessidade.

Comment: 2 - Teste do Google: Isto pode estar acontecendo porque o JSbin usa iframes e outros scripts dele. Você testou o link do JSbin ou testou uma url sua mesmo?
Se tiver interesse veja alguns vídeos que eu criei sobre Bootstrap no Youtube. Procure por "Bootstrap do Zero"

Comment: Na verdade, o vídeo está menor na vertical. Como arrumo isso? E sim, eu testei o link do JSbin, vou tentar testar no celular pelo host local

Comment: Felipe, você conseguiu?

Comment: Tinha arquivado esse projeto. Deu certo, obrigado!